# Custom Android Library Configurations

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

I have a library that I've currently broken into *two different* gradle modules.  One of the gradle modules provides a stub/dummy implementation of my library and I have another gradle module that provides the real implementation.  The reason for this, is that in certain flavors of my app, I want to only use stub implementation where the library does nothing whereas other flavors, I want to provide the real implementation.

In my app's build.gradle, I use the following "dependencies" block.

```
dependencies {
    flavorOneCompile project(":realLibrary")
    flavorTwoCompile project(":stubLibrary")
}
```

This solution seems to work okay but it bothers me that there are two gradle modules that I have to maintain.  It also makes it a bit clunky when I need to decide where to put class files (in real or in stub).  I should be able to just have a single library and somehow switch between the two types using gradle "configurations

https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.html

However, I haven't been able to learn how to do this yet.  I tried creating the "configurations" block in my android library as such

```
configurations {
    real
    stub
}
```

and then in my app's build.gradle, do the following.

```
dependencies {
    flavorOneCompile project(path ":myLib", configuration "real")
    flavorTwoCompile project(path ":myLib", configuration "stub")
}
```

This doesn't seem to work though.  Is there a way to achieve what I want? That is, have a single library so that my source code for my library is self-contained, but also provide different variations of my library?

Thanks!

Comment: I don' t think any other solution using gradle exists. You can provide this functionality with the logic of your code, i.e. like in-app-purchase mechanism, make the main functionality of your app dependant on some event has occured and if not, hide or disable it.